# How to name a two dimension checkbox?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, form-submit

This page has a list of week, user can check different day for different week

```
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Sun"/>
Sun
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Mon"/>
Mon
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Tue"/>
Tue
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Wed"/>
Wed
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Thu"/>
Thu
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Fri"/>
Fri
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Sat"/>
Sat
<br/>
<br/>


<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Sun"/>
Sun
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Mon"/>
Mon
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Tue"/>
Tue
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Wed"/>
Wed
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Thu"/>
Thu
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Fri"/>
Fri
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Sat"/>
Sat
<br/>
<br/>
.
.
.
<!-- can dynamically add more by javascript -->
```

But after submit, the all day will be combined in a 1D array

So I change week[] to week[][]

But it still combine all value in a 1D array, and each element of this array is an array

How to submit two dimension checkbox?

I expect I can use this to loop through all weeks and days, I don't want to hard code sequence number to weeks.

```
            foreach ($week as $oneWeek)
            {
                echo 'week<br>';
                foreach ($oneWeek as $day)
                {
                    echo $day.'<br>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you paraphrase your question? and whats the final output? if that goes into 1 dimensional only, how are you going to distinguish which week is it

Comment: In this HTML, you can see two lists of checkbox for two weeks, if user checked both Sun, how can I know which Sun for which week?

Comment: yes thats my point, you can't group them like that (1D), since there is no identifier which both sundays belong in their respective week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you group them this way:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $weeks = $_POST['week'];
    // in this way, you could identify the week for each day you checked
}


?>

<form method="POST">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[1][]" value="Sun"/>Sun</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[1][]" value="Mon"/>Mon</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[1][]" value="Tue"/>Tue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[1][]" value="Wed"/>Wed</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[1][]" value="Thu"/>Thu</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[1][]" value="Fri"/>Fri</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[1][]" value="Sat"/>Sat</label>

    <br/><br/>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[2][]" value="Sun"/>Sun</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[2][]" value="Mon"/>Mon</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[2][]" value="Tue"/>Tue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[2][]" value="Wed"/>Wed</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[2][]" value="Thu"/>Thu</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[2][]" value="Fri"/>Fri</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[2][]" value="Sat"/>Sat</label>

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Or this:

```
$days = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
?>

<form method="POST">
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++): ?> <!-- print week 1 to week 3 -->
        <?php foreach($days as $day): ?>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="week[<?php echo $i; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $day; ?>"/><?php echo $day; ?></label>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <br/><br/>
    <?php endfor; ?>

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: how to access it back after submit? to be specific from as post? need to loop again and get all?

Comment: @DevC just access the post values, your selected values should be inside it. its an array so most likely you'll access it using a loop

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a number in the first index.

First week:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="week[1]" value="Sun"/>
```

Second week

```
<input type="checkbox" name="week[2]" value="Sun"/>
```